# the center of amalgamated product of free groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $G_1$, $G_2$, $H$ be free groups, $K=G_1*_H G_2$ is the amalgamated product of free groups, then is center of $K$ trivial? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Take $\langle a, b \mid a^2 = b^2\rangle$. Then the centre is $\langle a^2\rangle$.  But, if both $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are non-abelian, then yes, because the centre of $K$ is $Z(G_{1})\cap Z(G_{2})\cap H$.

Comment: When $G_i$ are non-abelian, why is the center of $K$ that form?

Comment: @user151938 the center should be of that form no matter what the three groups are. Consider a word in the letters $G_1\cup G_2$. If it begins with something in $G_1\setminus H$, then anything else in $G_1\setminus H$ will fail to slide past it from left to right. If it begins with something in $G_2\setminus H$, same idea. So the center of $G_1*_HG_2$ is contained in $H$. Furthermore it must commute with all elements of $G_1$ and $G_2$, and if it does that then it commutes with all words formed out of letters from $G_1\cup G_2$ hence is central. Thus, the center is $Z(G_1)\cap Z(G_2)\cap H$.

Comment: What do you mean "fail to slide past it from left to right"?

Comment: @user151938 As is, $hg_1\neq g_1h$. The $h$ doesn't "slide past" the $g_1$.

Comment: But it is possible for $G_1$ and $G_2$ both to be nonabelian and for $Z(G_1) \cap Z(G_2) \cap H$ to be nontrivial.